# Why are all the indexes in my array being set to null after being set to another activity?

Tags: android, arrays

I have a game app where you can go into your inventory, which is another activity, and select items that you have picked up while playing the game then when you go back to the main game activity the items are used. To keep track of which of the 6 items the user wants to use I created a boolean array and set the corresponding index to true when an item is clicked then send it back to the main game activity. But when I go back to the main activity the app crashes when I try to check if an index is true. I used the debugger and found that all the indexes in my boolean array were set to null but they were all false in the inventory activity.

Game Activity

The app crashes once it gets to the if statement.

```
@Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        //this code checks if a item was used and calls the items method
        Intent Item= getIntent();
        boolean[] usedItem = Item.getBooleanArrayExtra(Inventory.tools);
        if (usedItem[0] == true) {
            breadItem();
        } else if (usedItem[1] == true) {
            potionItem();
        } else if (usedItem[2] == true) {
            swordItem();
        } 
    }
```

Inventory Activity

I have temporarily commented out working code that I believe has nothing to do with the problem

```
Intent Item= null;
    public static final String tools= "an item was used";

    boolean[] itemUsed = new boolean[6];

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventory);

        /*bread= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibBread);
        potion =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibPotion);
        sword =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibSword);
        wings =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibWings);
        bubble =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibBubble);
        teleport =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibTeleport);*/

        Item = new Intent(Inventory.this, MainGame.class);//data sent to MainGame activity

        /*ImageButton[] items = {bread, potion, sword, wings, bubble, teleport};
        Intent bag = getIntent();
        boolean[] boolItems = bag.getBooleanArrayExtra(MainGame.booInventory);

        for(int x =0; x <6; x +=1) {

            if (boolItems[x] == false)
            {
                items[x].setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.question_mark));
            }
        }*/

        Item.putExtra(tools, itemUsed);
    }
```

One of the six methods that set an index to true when the item is pressed. Also in Inventory activity

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void breadAction(View v)//lowers hunger by 2
    {
        bread= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibBread);

        if(bread.getDrawable() != getDrawable(R.drawable.question_mark))
        {
            //set image back to question mark
            bread.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.question_mark));

            itemUsed[0] = true;

            Item.putExtra(tools, itemUsed);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just suggestion if your index are unique then you can use Map and put the boolean values by using index :)

Comment: I see `Item.putExtra()` calls in both code snippets, but how is this `Intent` passed back to your game activity?

Comment: If you are meaning where is my startActivity(Item), I tried this but the problem is it restarts my game activity is there any way to pass the intent and resume the paused activity?